# Date calculation in Libre Office

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am using Libre Office 4.2 on ubuntu. I am not an expert in setting up formulae. My question is as follows.

I have dates in one column. I want the column next to it to show the number of days that have passed since the date in the previous column. 
For ex. For today, i.e. 25th of Feb, If column A has 21st of feb, B should read 4 days.

```
A                  B
21 Feb 2015      4 days
```

Is this possible at all? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract, it will give you the number of days.

```
=A2-A1
```

If A2 was 25 Feb and A1 was 21 Feb, the result will be 4.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to make the dates variable though? So that Every time I open the document, the difference is calculated? So if I open the doc tomorrow, It should give me 5

Comment: I think I may have got it.. First column will be the date, 2nd column will be "=TODAY()" and third column will be column subtraction. This will auto update tomorrow right?